# Fading Background then Go to Next Activity

Tags: android, transition

I just wanted to imitate famous games like Angry Birds wherein when you start the game, there are couple of screens, flashing then fading out, then go to another screen, fades out then the main menu comes out. How do i do that? Currently my code is this for the fading in and out. After implementing the code below, surprisingly, it did not animate. Any idea guys?

```
package com.kfc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Intro extends Activity {
    LinearLayout screen;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int i;
    Intent intent;
    TextView tv;
    Animation mAnim;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.introxml);

        screen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myintro);


        Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fade.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
             public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }
            @Override
             public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }
            @Override
             public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intro.this, NewKFCActivity.class));
                Intro.this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
             }

        });
        screen.startAnimation(fade);

    }
}
```

Comment: That's waay to overworked - try Activity#overridePendingTransition instead. Supply one or two XML alpha animations before calling startActivity and you are set: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29

Comment: @Jens i edited the code above.. i think i made a wrong implementation.. the program stops in the background and there are no fade ins whatsoever

Comment: **1**.Definitely skip the thread. **2**. You have a `View` available so do a `screen#postDelayed(new Runnable(){..}, 5000)` where you do your `#overridePendingTransition(..)` followed by `#startActivity` in the `#run()` method of the `Runnable` (**without** the call to `Thread#sleep(long)`).

Comment: @Jens i already edited the code above.. but still fails :(

Comment: Hm, what are you running on? I tried the same code and it faded between two activities without issue. Have you added log output to both activities `Activity#onCreate(Bundle)` methods?

Comment: wow thats weird.. its on Android 2.3.3 and in Eclipse.. are you sure that based on the code above, i was able to implement to codes correctly?

Comment: Yep, just slapped together two Activities with a differently colored background in both of them and did the transition as described earlier - faded between without a hitch. Do you get any log output that your NewKFC activity is starting?

Comment: yes it did.. it actually ran.. i can't understand :( just to make it clear, introxml is an xml file that contains my layout for the first activity.. myintro is the id of the linearlayout defined in introxml.. NewKFCActivity is the next layout (supposedly)

Comment: Well, it appears the problem lies in your `NewKFCActivity` then. Try replacing it with the most basic activity that only displays a Hello World message in a `TextView` (nothing fancy) and transition to that in your `Intro` activity.

Comment: @jens still no effect.. is it possible that the animation is so fast that i did not notice it?

Comment: The duration of the default fade_in/fade_out animations are set to @android:integer/config_longAnimTime, which is 400ms on a 2.3 device - so its definitely noticeable.

Comment: ow.. i tried a customized animation and still did not work.. like the alpha animation etc. i already placed my xml file above to make everything clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with activity animations.

Just after invoking `startActivity`, call

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

The first argument means that the activity you are about to start is going to fade in, the second argument specifies a fade-out animation for the activity that is currently in the foreground.

Comment: i edited the code above.. i think i made a wrong implementation.. the program stops in the background and there are no fade ins whatsoever

Comment: no surprise - you are starting a new activity in the `onCreate` method of another activity - the latter activity isn't even shown yet when `onCreate` is invoked. Perhaps you want to do it via a timer

Comment: wahh im getting confused now.. sorry i am very new here in android.. where should i now put the overridePendingTransition?

Comment: this will works 2.1 and above. overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);                                     startActivity(new Intent(Intro.this,NewKFCActivity.class));

Comment: that's weird. what are you observing now?

Comment: the background changed into the right activity but there is no animation.. how come?

Comment: oh I've just had an insight - maybe your device/emulator has animations disabled? you can check that somewhere in the settings, e.g. in the "Screen & Display" section

Comment: i think there is no problem there since when i used alpha animations in my buttons, they work.. not working only between activities

Comment: it already worked! i placed animationListener and it went well :) thanks

Comment: glad you got it working, but could you show the code you used? it's hard to imagine how to apply animation listener here o_O