# Override animation of finishing an activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I'd like to animate an activity in my app. This is absolutely fine if I start the activity, but when I try to finish it, android shows me first the standard and then the fade animation.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in);
}
```

Do you have an answer for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` These animations are for 2 Activitys.

1. For the one which is started
2. For the one which is finished

I hope I understand it right

Answer (score 4):

You need to call

`overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);`

just before you started your activity. After method `startActivity(Intent)` or `finish()`. The same question was already [aswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049917/fading-background-then-go-to-next-activity)

Comment: My problem is the finishing of the activity.

Comment: @MartinFink how you start this activity? In the same place where you start this activity

Comment: I start the activiy like this:
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in);
There the animation is no problem, only if I exit the aboutActivity I have this problem

Comment: Documentation of the method overridePendingTransition says:  Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Comment: Ok, got it now. The problem was that i used fade_out first, so it looked like it did two seperate animations. Sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing a while ago, Try overriding the transitions after calling `finish()` as well

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in);
```